# Conflicting type C for global variable

Tags: c

I wanted to use a file to have all my #define and constants: Example

```
 #ifndef CONSTANTS_H_
 #define CONSTANTS_H_

 #include <avr/io.h>

 //OVERALL DEFS
 #define TRUE 1
 #define FALSE 0


 // CLK_32MHz.h
 const uint8_t NEW_CLOCK_FREQ = 0b00000010;

 #endif /* CONSTANTS_H_ */
```

Then a different file to call it. Example:

```
#ifndef CLK_32MHZ_H_
#define CLK_32MHZ_H_

#include <avr/io.h>
#include "constants.h"

extern uint8_t NEW_CLOCK_FREQ;    

void Change_CLK_32HZ(){

    //Set the clk config
    OSC_CTRL = NEW_CLOCK_FREQ;

    //Wait for the right flag to be set in the OSC_STATUS reg 
    while((OSC_STATUS & PIN1_bm) != PIN1_bm);

    //Write the “IOREG” signature to the CPU_CCP reg
    CPU_CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;

    //Select the new clock source in the CLK_CTRL reg
    CLK_CTRL = CLK_SCLKSEL_RC32M_gc;

    return;
}
#endif /* CLK_32MHZ_H_ */
```

This is my main function:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "constants.h"
#include "Clk_32MHz.h"


int main(void){

}
```

This is the error I get on the terminal:

Conflicting type qualifiers for 'NEW_CLOCK_FREQ' File: Clk_32MHz.h
previous definition of 'NEW_CLOCK_FREQ' was here File: constants.h

Comment: `#define TRUE 1` Don't use homebrew boolean constant. Use the standard macros and type! And `const uint8_t NEW_CLOCK_FREQ = 0b00000010;` does not declare a constant, but a variable. C is not C++, there are no symbolic constants (except for enum constants which are near useless). This is C basics taught by good every C book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following...

in header.h:

```
extern const uint8_t myconst;
```

in foo.c:

```
#include "header.h"
const uint8_t myconst = 42;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I can't believe i didn't try that at first.